# What is the purpose of fetch listener in below code for service worker

Tags: service-worker

What is the purpose of fetch in below code.Can i send the request to get some data from the server ?

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
        console.log('Service worker installing...');
        self.skipWaiting();
    });

    self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
        console.log('Service worker activating...');
    });

    self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
        console.log('Fetching:', event.request.url);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are listening for `fetch` event(using the last function) the `event` object will contain the `url` from where you are trying to `fetch` a response using JS's `Fetch API`.

In the given piece of code, you are simply logging out the `url`. Notably, you are registering all the listeners inside an [`IIFE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) function.

However, if you want to send back a different response you may use `event.respondWith()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent/respondWith) you can read more about it.